# Can't resolve dns in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I use next command to check dns issue in my k8s:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
```

The nslookup result is:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

**dnsutils.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dnsutils
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dnsutils
    image: gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

**NOTE:** it's a machine which default disable all ports, so I ask our IT admin already open the port based on next doc [check-required-ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports), I'm not sure if this matters.

And use next I could get the pod ip of coredns.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide | grep core
coredns-7877db9d45-swb6c                                 1/1     Running   0          2m58s   10.244.1.8       node2   <none>           <none>
coredns-7877db9d45-zwc8v                                 1/1     Running   0          2m57s   10.244.0.6       node1   <none>           <none>
```

Here, `10.244.0.6` is my master while `10.244.1.8` is my working node.

Then if I directly specify coredns pod ip:

**master node ok:**

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default 10.244.0.6
Server:         10.244.0.6
Address:        10.244.0.6#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

**work node not ok:**

```
# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default 10.244.1.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

So, the question narrow down to why COREDNS on work node not works? Anything I need to pay attention?

**Environment:**

- OS: ubuntu18.04
- K8S: v1.21.0
- Cluster boot command:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Comment: It's very, very diffucult to grasp what you are doing there. Would you mind try to rephrase the question so that It will be more readable? Also what OS you are running this? How did you bootstrapped you cluster?

Comment: Mind sharing `kubectl get no -o wide` ?

Comment: Have you gone thru all the prerequisites before creating the cluster? Have you disabled the swap off (`sudo swapoff -a`)?

Comment: where have you spun off your cluster? on-premises, or with any other cloud provider?

Comment: Thanks all, late response as just back from vacation. Finally, I find the root cause is hardware firewall block for flannel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I find the root cause, this is hardware firewall issue, see [this](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#firewalls):

> **Firewalls**
> When using udp backend, flannel uses UDP port 8285 for sending encapsulated packets.
> When using vxlan backend, kernel uses UDP port 8472 for sending encapsulated packets.
> Make sure that your firewall rules allow this traffic for all hosts participating in the overlay network.
> Make sure that your firewall rules allow traffic from pod network cidr visit your kubernetes master node.

- When `nslookup client` on the same node of `dns server`, it won't trigger firewall block, so everything is ok.
- When `nslookup client` not on the same node of `dns server`, it will trigger firewall block, so we can't access dns server.

So, after open the ports, everything ok now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Amazon's Kubernetes (EKS) and this error was due to a bad security group. Using the default launch template for the AWS managed nodegroup fixed the issue.